# How to detect data change in timeseries

Tags: python, time-series, detection

How to detect the start time when the value in timeseries start to change very fast using python? And the end time when the value start normal again as shown in picture below.

Time series data with steady and high frequency:

[image]

Comment: As anomaly detection is a broad field - could you describe, what you tried so far? How about applying a a Discrete Fourier Transformation to see the frequence spectrum?

Comment: Changepoint detection is almost bound to be algorithm-specific.  If needed, one more algorithm to test is https://pypi.org/project/Rbeast/, which is a Bayesian method that is relatively fast for typical signals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[changepoint detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection)** algorithms to do so. `ruptures` is a good library to do so. Check their [GitHub page](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures) for more information.

A simple example of using `ruptures`:

```py
import ruptures as rpt

signal = ...

algo = rpt.Pelt(model="rbf").fit(signal)
result = algo.predict(pen=10)
```

Comment: I have tried using Ruptures, but it is very slow and capture many points instead of start time/end time of data transient (data with high frequency)

Comment: Ruptures is not fast indeed, however you can optimize the output by changing the pen parameter to different values. I've used this on a more complicated signal and it serves the purpose

Comment: There are statistical methods as well, but they require more manual implementation.